# SystemVerilog Assertion Error : Illegal use of non-constant expression

Tags: system-verilog, assertions, system-verilog-assertions

SLV_DCR_TIMEOUT_WAIT is the value programmed in the register hence it is not a constant value. How can I use the same in assertion.

```
assign DCR_CLK = testbench.sw_top_inst.DUT.megatron_x.megatron_cib.dcr_slave_cfg.DCR_clk;
assign DCR_TIMEOUT_WAIT = testbench.sw_top_inst.DUT.megatron_x.megatron_cib.dcr_slave_cfg.dcr_timeout_wait[15:0];
assign SLV_DCR_TIMEOUT_WAIT = testbench.sw_top_inst.DUT.megatron_x.megatron_cib.dcr_slave_cfg.Sl_dcrTimeoutWait;
assign SCRUB_INIT = testbench.sw_top_inst.DUT.megatron_x.megatron_cib.dcr_slave_cfg.scrub_init;

// end

//=================ASSERTION TO CHECK SLV_DCR_TIMEOUT_WAIT============================//
property slv_dcr_timeout_wait;
    @(posedge DCR_CLK) disable iff (!DCR_TIMEOUT_WAIT)
        $rose(SCRUB_INIT) |-> $rose(SLV_DCR_TIMEOUT_WAIT) ##(DCR_TIMEOUT_WAIT) $fell(SLV_DCR_TIMEOUT_WAIT);
endproperty: slv_dcr_timeout_wait

assert property (slv_dcr_timeout_wait);
```

Error message :

> Error-[SVA-INCE] Illegal use of non-constant expression
>   /lsi/designs/rsd_megatron/team/singhs/megatron/sim/testbench/mss_tb/interfaces/mss_internal_signal_if.sv, 41
>   mss_internal_signal_if, "DCR_TIMEOUT_WAIT"
>   The use of a non-constant expression is not allowed in properties, sequences
>   and assertions for cases such as delay and repetition ranges.
>   Please replace the offending expression by an elaboration-time constant.

Comment: Please format your question & do not ALL CAPS your title.

Answer (score 1):

As you noticed, the issue is with `##(DCR_TIMEOUT_WAIT)`, SystemVerilog want it to be a constant value. I use local variable counters to get around this. See [IEEE Std 1800-2012](https://standards.ieee.org/findstds/standard/1800-2012.html) § 16.10 *Local variables*

Using a local variables create a generic pulse checking sequences:

```
sequence pulse_seq(local logic sig, local int limit);
  int cnt = limit;
  $rose(sig) ##0 (sig && cnt>0, cnt--)[*] ##1 ($fell(sig) && cnt==0);
endsequence
```

Then plug it into the assertion:

```
property slv_dcr_timeout_wait;
  @(posedge DCR_CLK)
  $rose(SCRUB_INIT) && (DCR_TIMEOUT_WAIT>0)  |->
    pulse_seq(SLV_DCR_TIMEOUT_WAIT,DCR_TIMEOUT_WAIT);
endproperty : slv_dcr_timeout_wait

assert property (slv_dcr_timeout_wait);
```

Note that I removed `disable iff (!DCR_TIMEOUT_WAIT)`and to the trigger I changed the trigger condition to `$rose(SCRUB_INIT) && (DCR_TIMEOUT_WAIT>0)`. Disable is asynchronous action and should be used to abort a sequence that already started.

Proof of concept [here](http://www.edaplayground.com/x/8GP) (Note: Riviera-PRO EDU 2014.10 does not appear to properly support `sequence` port lists to I had to hard coded the signals. Should work in any full simulator that supports IEEE Std 1800-2005 or greater)